80's or early 90's movie (possibly made for tv) about a guy retrieving a kidnapped kid
OK, very little to go on, but I remember watching this movie where a guy is trying to retrieve a kidnapped kid (maybe his own kid) from a bad guy who may have been played by Lance Henriksen but I could be making that up.
I remember at the end, the bad guy is hanging onto the bottom of the car that the guy and the kid are trying to escape in, and I think the driver runs over some of those parking lot spikes to get rid of him.  I think there was also a part in the movie where someone gets shot on an escalator and they slide down the banister leaving a streak of blood.

yes! that's it, you've  put my mind to ease after 25 years!

Hit List from 1989 with Lance Henriksen as an evil hitman.

Gangster boss Vincent Luca shall appear in court to account for his crimes - but he has a man at the police who tells him names and locations of the witnesses, so he can kill them all - but one: In the last hit, the professional killer gets into the wrong house. When the owner Mark Collins comes home, he finds his pregnant wife unconscious in the kitchen, his friend dead in the living room and his son kidnapped. The police officer wants Luca to believe he has the real witness' son and sends Collins into prison. But he manages to escape and takes things into his own hands.

The scene with the car and the spikes actually appears in the poster and in the trailer (near the end):



